# LinearLayout * size element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout that works great to produce something like:

[ fixed image size ] [ fixed image size ] [ text takes up the space that is left ]

The XML looks similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to reverse it, have another view that looks like:

[ text takes up space that is left ] [ fixed image size ] [ fixed image size ]

So I naturally did the obvious thing which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But in this case, the text just goes over the entire width, because width is fill_parent.. but I don't want it to wrap_content either.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set textview1's width to 0dp and add a layout_weight element = 1.

Comment: Wow thanks. Worked perfectly. I'll mark as answer in a few minutes.